# Woocommerce Invoices number by Language

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I needed to advise about the woocommerce plug-in invoice, do you know any way of doing this if we have more languages ​​on the site, such as EN, PL, CZ, HUN, so for each language we need separate invoice numbering. That means if the EN buyer purchases the product, then the invoice number starts 20190001 and if another client comes from the PL and purchases the product so that his invoice is again 20190001 because it is from another country? And so for all countries, each has a separate number of invoices.

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

A large part of the value of having an invoice number is that it uniquely identifies a transaction.  If you implement your strategy, you will always need two pieces of information to identify the invoice, specifically the invoice number and the language code.  If the language code is a business requirement, I would suggest you use a smart number format.  A smart number is a unique identifier that communicates additional information about the entity identified.  For example, in your case, the first invoice could be EN001, the second invoice PL002.  The first two characters are a language code.  The second three characters are a sequential number, and you know by looking at the second three characters that this was the n-th invoice created.

A disadvantage of using sequential numbers is that you expose some information about the volume of your business.  This is sometimes illustrated as the "German Tank Problem", based on the story of how the Allies in World War 2 used the serial numbers found on captured / destroyed German tanks to estimate manufacturing capabilities, and subsequently the number of tanks the Germans had.  More info:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_tank_problem

You could use a series of number for each language code, such as EN001 and PL001, but you would decrease the amount of information coded in the invoice number, and you would have a harder implementation in WooCommerce since you would need to maintain index numbers for all languages in order to create the unique invoice number for each invoice.

Comment: thanks for reply, and ye my client want something like you wrote EN001 and PL001, but i don't know how can i implement this into woocommerce for best working